# Move by word in bash 

Tags: bash, navigation

In bash, you can move to the beginning of the line with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and the end with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. How can I move forward and backward by word?

Comment: Another handy reference for bash keyboard shortcuts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Keyboard_shortcuts

Answer (score 24):

With emacs bindings:

<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> moves back a word and <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> moves forward a word.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> moved back a character and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> moves forward a character.

So <kbd>B</kbd> vs <kbd>F</kbd> is backwards vs forward and <kbd>Meta</kbd> vs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is word vs character.

The exact mapping of <kbd>Meta</kbd> may vary between keyboards.  Try holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while pressing the other key; if that doesn't work, press and release <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then press the other key.

Answer (score 8):

use alt+b for backward and alt+f for forward movement by a word.

Answer (score 6):

Put in `~/.inputrc`:

```
# Ctrl+Left/Right to move by whole words.
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
# Same with Shift pressed.
"\e[1;6C": forward-word
"\e[1;6D": backward-word
```

`showkey -a` in the terminal will tell you which ANSI codes are emitted by terminal on key press, for `Ctrl+Right` I got:

```
bash# showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^[[1;5C          27 0033 0x1b
         91 0133 0x5b
         49 0061 0x31
         59 0073 0x3b
         53 0065 0x35
         67 0103 0x43
```

`^[` is `ESC` which is `\e` in `~/.inputrc`. You can try it on the fly with Bash built-in `bind`:

```
bind '"\e[1;5C": forward-word'
```

or dump current bindings with:

```
bind -p
```